# Changing size of modal view controller properly with presentViewController:animated:completion:

Tags: objective-c, ios5, resize, ios6, presentmodalviewcontroller

Prior to IOS 6 I used below code to present modal view with customized size:

```
- (void) showModalViewWithController:(GUIViewController*) _viewController {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:_viewController animated:YES];
    _viewController.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    _viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
        _viewController.view.superview.frame.origin.x,
        _viewController.view.superview.frame.origin.y,
        700.0f,
        self.view.frame.size.height - 80.f);
    _viewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Now I have to change the function

```
- (void)presentModalViewController: (UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag
```

to

```
- (void)presentViewController: (UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion
```

Unfortunately adjusting size do not work well after the change like that:

```
- (void) showModalViewWithController:(GUIViewController*) _viewController {
    [self presentViewController:_viewController animated:YES completion:^(){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
        _viewController.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        _viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
            _viewController.view.superview.frame.origin.x,
            _viewController.view.superview.frame.origin.y,
            700.0f,
            self.view.frame.size.height - 80.f);
        _viewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }];
}
```

because the modal view is presented before it's frame manipulation and it jumps after invoking the completion block.

How to deal with that?

Thanks in advance,

Michał

Comment: Have you tried keeping it the same as before and leaving the completion block blank? Adding all the code into the block should do exactly as you said, present the view and then the animations would occur.

Comment: Yes, I tried not to use the completion block but it works only in iOS 5. iOS 6 demands then additional screen rotation to redraw the view properly.

Comment: hi! Any solution?? I'm facing the same problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why the completion block animation would jump.  I've never user the `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` method.  I usually call the block based animation methods like `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:]`.  This is because the use of beginAnimations method is discouraged in iOS 4 and above.

I would try changing your animation to use the block based method instead.  There could be some weird threading issues going on after you commit your animations.

I find it rather interesting you're resizing the view *after* displaying it instead of resizing it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

AHKNavigationController *navigationController = [[AHKNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:moreOverView];

[navigationController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

```
    navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0)
    {
        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
                    //Make the modal bigger than normal
                navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
                                                                       navigationController.view.superview.frame.origin.x,
                                                                       navigationController.view.superview.frame.origin.y,
                                                                       540,
                                                                       622
                                                                       );
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            }];
        }];
    }
    else{
        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
        navigationController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(540,622);
        navigationController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
    }
    navigationController.view.superview.autoresizingMask =
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

where AHKNavigationController is found at https://github.com/fastred/AHKNavigationController